# Chrome DevTools: How to copy a JSON object as text from the Sources tab or Watch pane

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, devtools

I'm stepping through my page's javascript with Chrome DevTools, I've put a watch on my variable.  I just need the JSON object as text.

Comment: It's a JS Object. To turn it into JSON text, use `console.log(JSON.stringify(some_object));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can print your object in the following way in your code:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(your_object));
```